# White space on form

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS, have been experimenting when I ran into this problem and I am stuck.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "window">
  <form>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: caviarDreams;
    src: url(./CaviarDreams.ttf);
}
html *
{
    font-family:caviarDreams; 
    cursor:  url(./cursor.png), auto;
    background: url(./background.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.button {
    border: none;
    text-indent:0;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:39px;
    font-size: 15px; 
    background:url(./buttonNormal.png) no-repeat; 
    width:230px;
    height:71px;
}
.button:active { 
    background:url(./buttonActive.png) no-repeat; 
}
.button:hover { 
    background:url(./buttonHover.png) no-repeat;
}
.window {
    background: url('./window.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 624px 696px;
    width:624px;
    height:696px;
}
```

---

Below is the snippet and a fiddle demo is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cnn7uw68). Weird, on the fiddle there is no problem.

```css
html * {
  background: url(./background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.button {
  border: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 39px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ZD9nn7F.png) no-repeat;
  width: 230px;
  height: 71px;
}
.button:active {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/K5mD1ga.png) no-repeat;
}
.button:hover {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Yh2wITG.png) no-repeat;
}
.window {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/0ZQwEeS.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 624px 696px;
  width: 624px;
  height: 696px;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <form>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>

</div>
```

**How it looks like:**

[image]

**How it should look:**

[image]

When I remove the `<form>` the "white space" disappears. Can you give any advice how to fix it ?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Can you put the code on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Can you give any advice how to fix it

Comment: weird, on the fiddle there is not problem - http://jsfiddle.net/cnn7uw68/

Comment: I have added the images from the link into the question and also created a snippet based on the fiddle you had provided in comments. Always edit in all relevant information into the question itself because comments can go unnoticed. I have also compressed your code blocks by removing extra line breaks. When using HTML tags inline (like `<form>`) enclose them within backticks. Otherwise they get treated as normal HTML tags and do not show up on screen as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove * from html * { .. } and it's fixed now, i feel stupid

Comment: Because in fiddle i don't have background(was too big to upload it), from there i realised what was going on